# React axios interceptor does not seem to catch anything

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I'm trying to use axios interceptor to redirect the user to the login page when his session expired but I can not make it work. 
I'm logging the response or error but i never get anything in my console.

axios configuration :

```
import { API_URL } from "@kpt/utils/constants";
import type { AxiosInstance } from "axios";
import axios from "axios";

type ClientT = Pick<AxiosInstance, "get" | "post" | "delete" | "options" | "patch" | "put">;

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  withCredentials: true,
}) as ClientT;

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    console.log("response here", response);
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error here", error);
    window.location.href = "/signin";
  },
);

export default client;
```

An example of an API call :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const results = await client.get(GET_COMPONENTS_TYPE);
        ...
      } catch (error: any) {
       ...
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I never used interceptors before. 
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your `response`? Is the backend sending `session expired` as 200 status code? If so then you need to add a conditional within this part of your code:

`(response) => {
    console.log("response here", response);
    return response;
  }`